# remote keyboard not recognized

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm logged into a remote server using putty ssh. The problem is that keyboard keys are not working as I was expecting. I'm talking about directional keys and tab.

TAB is working as in MS Windows, but in CLI, I need the auto-complete feature.

Can you help me with some advices?

**UPDATE:** on `ps - p $$` it says that I'm using sh.

Comment: What is your current shell? Not all shells support auto-complete! You can find out your shell by typing `ps -p $$`. Also, your title is misleading.

Comment: Use `echo $SHELL` to find out what shell you're using.

Comment: @ott-- `echo $0` or `ps -p $$` show you the shell you are currently running. `echo $SHELL` shows your login shell which may not be your current shell.

Comment: case you want bash auto-complete a .bashrc must be present, touch .bashrc is sufficient retype bash again (one time only) should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the *loadkeys* function

```
$ man loadkeys
```

Maybe you just need to load the proper keymap corresponding to your keyboard layout. Have a look at the directory containing the *keymaps* (it varies between distributions: /usr/share/keymaps/, /lib/kbd/keymaps/, ...) and load the correct keymap.

Example to load the Spanish keymap:

```
$ loadkeys /lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/es.map.gz
```

Comment: No explanation regarding the negative vote?